# Datatable count all the different varieties

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

In my datatable I am trying to count all the different varieties of a column. In the sample below I want the output to count yes,no and then add all the yes no together. I tried the fnFooterCallback but I am not getting the values?

```
Output 
Yes 1
No  2
Total Votes (Y+N)   3
```

```js
var table = $('#question').dataTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="question">
  <tr>
    <th>Question 1</th>
    <th>Question 2</th>
    <th>Question 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Hot</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Cold</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Hot</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "_tried the fnFooterCallback_" - Can you show us your attempt and what happens when you run it (e.g. any errors)?

Comment: There are various questions which show how to create [DataTables column totals](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+show+column+sum+site:stackoverflow.com), and other questions which show how to [count occurrences](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+count+occurrences+in+array+site:stackoverflow.com) using JavaScript. Maybe you can combine the two techniques. Otherwise, can you show us where you are getting stuck, specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using vanilla JS below seems to give what you are looking for. This would be much simpler with a different html structure if you control that. But this should give you a prototype to work from and refactor to fit your needs.

```js
const 
  //get the answers as an array
  answers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.answers td')).map(function (a) {   return a.innerText; }),
  //get the questions as an array
  questions = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.questions th')),
  //get the length of the questions
  qLen = questions.length,
  //create a dictionary object
  dict = {};
let arr;
//loop the questions array
questions.forEach(function (q, i) {
  //set the var arr to an array of answers matching the column of the question
  arr = answers.filter(function (a, ai) { return (ai - i) % qLen == 0; });
  //set the dictionary line to an empty object
  dict[q.innerText] = {};
  arr
    //uniquify the answers
    .filter(function (x, i) { return arr.indexOf(x) === i; })
    //loop the uniquified answers to set the dictionary.question = the answer
    //then set the dictionary.question.answer = count
    .forEach(function (x) { dict[q.innerText][x] = arr.filter(function(a) { return a == x; }).length; });
});
//result is a dictionary that can be drilled down into a count via dict.question.answer
console.log(dict);
```

```html
<table id="question">
  <tr class="questions">
    <th>Question 1</th>
    <th>Question 2</th>
    <th>Question 3</th>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75522879/datatable-count-all-the-different-varieties#
  </tr>
  <tr class="answers">
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Hot</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="answers">
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Cold</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="answers">
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Hot</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just an observation: Be aware, this won't handle DataTables pagination, if the expectation is to see grand totals _across_ multiple pages of rows. It will only handle the currently visible data (as displayed in the DOM) - but _not_ any of the additional data stored in DataTables (but not currently visible).

Comment: Very valid point to bear in mind for the op. thank you for the notation